# How to collapse a specific section of footer menu after click on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, footer

I'm trying to create a responsive footer for mobile so that when users click on one of the titles the  elements of that section expand while the other  elements of the other  remain collapsed and when clicked again it collapses.
So far I only manage to create a functionality where after clicking one  all element of all  expands.

HTML

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="nav-footer">
    <div class="nav">
      <h2 class="title">Legal</h2>
      <ul class="list">
        <li>Privacy Policy</li>
        <li>Terms & Conditions</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <h2 class="title">Company</h2>
      <ul class="list">
        <li>About us</li>
        <li>Mission</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <h2 class="title">Assistance</h2>
      <ul class="list">
        <li>FAQ</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.list {
  max-height: 0; 
  overflow:hidden; 
  transition: max-height 1s ease-out;
}

.title {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.test {
  height:auto; 
  max-height: 500px; 
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in !important;
}
```

JS

```
jQuery(" h2").click(function(){
    $("ul").toggleClass("test");
});
```

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: `$("ul")` selects all `ul` element across the whole document; you need to limit this to a proper context - for example, by going up from the clicked `h2` to the `.nav` element first (`.parent()`/`.parents()`), and then `.find()` the `ul` in there. (Or by passing it as context to a `$(...)` selection.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$(this).next("ul").toggleClass("test");` to find the ul "related" to your h2.

**Demo**

```js
jQuery(" h2").click(function(){
    $(this).next("ul").toggleClass("test");
});
```

```css
.list {
  max-height: 0; 
  overflow:hidden; 
  transition: max-height 1s ease-out;
}

.title {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.test {
  height:auto; 
  max-height: 500px; 
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="nav-footer">
    <div class="nav">
      <h2 class="title">Legal</h2>
      <ul class="list">
        <li>Privacy Policy</li>
        <li>Terms & Conditions</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <h2 class="title">Company</h2>
      <ul class="list">
        <li>About us</li>
        <li>Mission</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <h2 class="title">Assistance</h2>
      <ul class="list">
        <li>FAQ</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```